# Cucumbers not producing

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, cucumbers

I have 3 cucumber plants that I started indoors from seeds. They were all off to a great start but after producing 1-2 cucumbers I noticed the don't look as healthy and leaves have turned yellow. I see new growth in some places. Is this normal?  Are we at the end of cucumber season?  What should I do differently?  I am in San Francisco area.

[image]
[image]

Comment: To me, it seems that they lack of nutrients.

Comment: Are the old leaves or new leaves yellowing?

Comment: What have you done for fertilizer?  Any other chemicals, concoctions?  How do you water?  I see the drip stuff.  This does look like either low nitrogen and/or iron deficiency.  The nitrogen in a fertilizer for any vegetable that is reproductive (versus green leafy stuff like lettuce) has to be less than the phosphorus and potassium.  But some nitrogen is critical.  Do not put high nitrogen on these plants as you will never get any cucumbers.  Let us know!!

Comment: Watering 3 times a week using drip and occasionally manual watering if soil looks dry.  Last time I fertilized was a month back using organic fertilizer bought from the store.  It was specifically for vegetables and had low nitrogen.

Comment: Is this one of your raised beds?

Comment: yes and this one has another cucumber plant.  I have another cucumber plant in a different raised bed that is showing similar symptoms

Comment: There are mosaic viruses that turn leaves yellow etc.  Can you take a close up picture of a leaf?

Comment: Added a close up picture

Answer (score 5):

A lot of things could be happening. Lack of nutrients or too much fertilizer. Could also be the ph. Test the soil. Cucumbers like a ph of about 5.5. I would also put mulch on the ground around them so the soil stays moist for a longer period. The ground looks very dry.

Comment: Yes!  Get a simple soil test for pH.  If the pH is not correct, then the chemicals the plant needs with which to make its own food are not going to be available.